# Paratemers in URL get first child in tree and not the selected one Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm having an specific issue regarding to my page, I'll try to explain what is going on.

I generate a list with sections in my page. Like this:

```
<ul class="menu__list--nested active">
   <li class="menu__item" data-value="QlRxM25vS,4"><span> test </span>
      <ul class="menu__list--nested active">
         <li class="menu__item" data-value="c1hjS2hIV,5"><span> test </span></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="menu__item" data-value="OVQrV05iZ,4"><span> test </span>
      <ul class="menu__list--nested active">
         <li class="menu__item" data-value="Z1BoQUc5,5"><span> test </span></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="menu__item" data-value="SmVQT,4"><span> test </span>
      <ul class="menu__list--nested active">
         <li class="menu__item" data-value="UUZZY2M,5"><span> test </span></li>
         <li class="menu__item" data-value="S0FSc,5"><span> test </span></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="menu__item" data-value="QkpEdG96,4"><span> test </span>
      <ul class="menu__list--nested active">
         <li class="menu__item" data-value="Yzh3Ui8y,5"><span> test </span>
            <ul class="menu__list--nested active">
               <li class="menu__item" data-value="dDdVUWJ,6"><span> test </span></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="menu__item" data-value="TkN6SHZuM1,4"><span> test </span></li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, its a list inside a list in order to make a tree sepparated by levels, the important values of this list are the **data-value** of **li**

Now, my javascript file has this method that gets the selected **li** value

```
    $('.menu__item').click(function(){         
        var dataValue = $(this).data('value');
        var idSeccionConNivel = dataValue.split(",");
        var idSeccion = idSeccionConNivel[0];
        var busqueda = $('#name_input').val();
        debugger;
        if (idSeccionConNivel.length>1){
            var nivel = idSeccionConNivel[1];
            window.location.href = "listado-articulos.php?" + 'seccion=' + idSeccion + '&nivel=' + nivel + '&search_query='+busqueda;
        }else{
            window.location.href = "listado-articulos.php?" + 'seccion=' + idSeccion + '&search_query='+busqueda;
        }       
    });
```

As you can see, it triggers when you click a **li** with **.menu__item** class, it gets the data-value and do other stuff. This function only activates when I click the specific **li** and get the data-value of that tag, the problem I'm having is, when I assign window.location.href the values I selected it takes only the first li value.

FOr example, if I click on `<li class="menu__item" data-value="UUZZY2M,5"></li>` the function assign **seccion** to UUZZY2M and **nivel** to 5, but the window.loaction.href change the url parameters to the li father, in this case: SmVQT and 4

I debug the function and enters only one time since window.location.href loads the page (it loads the same page if you need to know but using new parameters). What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How is this question/issue related to PHP?

Comment: True, corrected the tags, the problem I'm having is more related to javascript and jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that the nested nature of the `li` elements means that [event bubbling](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing) is happening. If you assign `e` for [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) to the function call and then use [e.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) you can click on a deeply nested `li` and it will use the values from that rather than the top-level parent and all in between.

```js
$('.menu__item').click(function(e){ 
    e.stopPropagation();
    var dataValue = $(this).data('value');
    var idSeccionConNivel = dataValue.split(",");
    var idSeccion = idSeccionConNivel[0];
    var busqueda = $('#name_input').val();

    let url;
    
    
    if (idSeccionConNivel.length>1){
        var nivel = idSeccionConNivel[1];
        url = "listado-articulos.php?" + 'seccion=' + idSeccion + '&nivel=' + nivel + '&search_query='+busqueda;
    }else{
        url = "listado-articulos.php?" + 'seccion=' + idSeccion + '&search_query='+busqueda;
    }
    alert( url );
    location.href=url;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<ul class="menu__list--nested active">
   <li class="menu__item" data-value="QlRxM25vS,4"><span> test </span>
      <ul class="menu__list--nested active">
         <li class="menu__item" data-value="c1hjS2hIV,5"><span> test </span></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="menu__item" data-value="OVQrV05iZ,4"><span> test </span>
      <ul class="menu__list--nested active">
         <li class="menu__item" data-value="Z1BoQUc5,5"><span> test </span></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="menu__item" data-value="SmVQT,4"><span> test </span>
      <ul class="menu__list--nested active">
         <li class="menu__item" data-value="UUZZY2M,5"><span> test </span></li>
         <li class="menu__item" data-value="S0FSc,5"><span> test </span></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="menu__item" data-value="QkpEdG96,4"><span> test </span>
      <ul class="menu__list--nested active">
         <li class="menu__item" data-value="Yzh3Ui8y,5"><span> test </span>
            <ul class="menu__list--nested active">
               <li class="menu__item" data-value="dDdVUWJ,6"><span> test </span></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="menu__item" data-value="TkN6SHZuM1,4"><span> test </span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: YES, I didn't see if you change to alert the event fires N times until it reaches the father li, I guess it doesn't care if you are using location.href, you have to stop the propagation in order to prevent this.